# jquery offset values changes by scrolling the page

Tags: jquery

```
var offset = $(selector).offset();
```

The values of offset variable changes if we scroll the page up and down, i want the exact and fixed offset values while keeping the position of the "selector" default(static).How can i do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could always calculate the offset, factoring in the scroll position:

```
var offset_t = $(selector).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
var offset_l = $(selector).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
```

Comment: but my document is in the iframe, sorry for not mentioning this point in question

Comment: Where will the code be placed, within the parent window or iframe?

Comment: I've got the same problem and this is not a solution. Offset is not supposed to do this, how do I fix the actual issue?

Comment: sorry, turns out I had multiple elements with same #id

Answer (score 9):

One other potential cause is if your `<body>` happens to have CSS that sets `overflow-x: hidden;` - that completely breaks jQuery's `offset()` method.

In that case, `$(window).scrollTop()` is always 0, so the accepted answer does not work.

Comment: Is there any alternative plan to get the position so I can scroll the the specific div (I have overflow hidden set on the body)?

Comment: Oof, I'm sorry. I wish I had posted something more useful when I wrote that. I don't remember at this point.

Answer (score 9):

I had a very similar issue to the original question. The offset is kinda tricky. Hopefully, this will help solve your problems as it did mine. I have 3 JSFiddles to demonstrate.

1. If you are basing the `offset().top` of your div element from the window, you will always get a static number (i.e. if the `$(window)` is the thing that scrolls and you have a div inside the window with `offset().top` applied, the div will always have a static number). This offset is the exact number of pixels the element exists from the top of the `$(window)` no matter how far down you scroll. For each of my JSFiddles, I'll see how far down the object `$('div#offset')` is from the top of it's scrolling container. In this first example, notice how the number doesn't change:

https://jsfiddle.net/BrianIsSecond/ehkgh2gu/

2. Now, lets say that the `$(window)` isn't the container that scrolls. You instead create a div that has an "overflow-y:scroll;" attribute set. In this case, the `$('div#offset').offset().top` acts very differently than the previous example. You'll notice it changes as you scroll. For my JSFiddle example, I simply wrapped everything in `div#overflow` that has `overflow-y:scroll;` attribute set. See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/BrianIsSecond/tcs390h6/ <--- Note too that div#overflow isn't 100% tall. I made it 100px short of 100%. I am using that to illustrate an easy mistake, which I will address next.

3. If your like me, example 2 isn't what you were wanting. The best solution I have found is to grab `$('#overflow').scrollTop()` and add it to `$('#offset').offset().top` (i.e. `var ep = $('#offset').offset().top + $('#overflow').scrollTop()`). Basically, by adding these two changing numbers together, they 'sorta' cancel each other out, giving you the exact position of the `div#offset` element... or do they? Well, this is where the position of the `div#overflow` is important! You must, must, must take into account the position of the scrollable container. To do this, take `$('#overflow').offset().top` and subtract it from `$('#offset').offset().top` before you add `$('#overflow').scrollTop()`. This will then factor in the position of the scrollable container from the window. See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/BrianIsSecond/yzc5ycyg/

Ultimately, what you are looking for is something like this:

```
var w = $('#overflow'),   // overflow-y:scroll;
    e = $('#offset');     // element

$('#overflow').scroll(function(){
    var wh = w.height(),                             // window height
        sp = w.scrollTop(),                          // scroll position
        ep = (e.offset().top - w.offset().top) + sp; // element position

    console.log(ep);
});
```

---

UPDATE (10/11/17): I've created a function to help solve this problem. Enjoy!

```
/*
function: betterOffset
hint: Allows you to calculate dynamic and static offset whether they are in a div container with overscroll or not.

            name:           type:               option:         notes:
@param      s (static)      boolean             required        default: true | set false for dynamic
@param      e (element)     string or object    required
@param      v (viewer)      string or object    optional        If you leave this out, it will use $(window) by default. What I am calling the 'viewer' is the thing that scrolls (i.e. The element with "overflow-y:scroll;" style.).

@return                  numeric
*/
function betterOffset(s, e, v) {
    // Set Defaults
        s = (typeof s == 'boolean') ? s : true;
        e = (typeof e == 'object') ? e : $(e);
        if (v != undefined) {v = (typeof v == 'object') ? v : $(v);} else {v = null;}

    // Set Variables
        var w = $(window),              // window object
            wp = w.scrollTop(),         // window position
            eo = e.offset().top;        // element offset
        if (v) {
            var vo = v.offset().top,    // viewer offset
                vp = v.scrollTop();     // viewer position
        }

    // Calculate
        if (s) {
            return (v) ? (eo - vo) + vp : eo;
        } else {
            return (v) ? eo - vo : eo - wp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add my answer here after having the same issues:

After getting the behaviour described above [I looked at the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and discovered that

> jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of **hidden** elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.

The element I was trying to get the offset of was in fact set to `display:none;` giving me a false offset which changed when scrolling (even though the element didn't move).

So make sure you're not trying to get an offset of a hidden element! hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same problem while editing a old website the workaround I find out is to use **$(selector)[0].offsetTop** instead of $(selector).offset().top and it is working fine for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that correct answer is not mentioned. Because there can be couple of nested scrolling containers. I use recursive calculation in such cases

```
/*el - JQuery object */
let x=0,y=0;
let offs_p=el.get(0);
while (offs_p)
{
    y+=offs_p.offsetTop+offs_p.scrollTop;
    x+=offs_p.offsetLeft+offs_p.scrollLeft;
    offs_p = offs_p.offsetParent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In 2015, the 'correct' answer should no longer be used - offset has been modified. Any code that used the above solution will no longer work properly.

Solution: Please upgrade jquery to a newer version (works in 1.11.3).
Or... change .offset call to use .position instead.

Comment: I believe your advice is wrong here, offset and position are independant of each other and potentially two different values. Offset is relative to the document, Position is relative to the (offset) parent.

Comment: @m.t.bennet You shouldn't downgrade because you 'believe' it is wrong. I had this exact problem, and fixed it using either way I mentioned, when dealing with 'fixed' positioning. I realize they are two different things, and will give different numbers, but it is an alternative if you cannot upgrade jquery.

Comment: perhaps putting a comment educating people that these are in fact different properties but may in fact offer a solution IF not using fixed positioning. Regardless your advice here is incorrect, jQuery version does not matter with respect to the question and the 'correct' answer is still appropriate.