# jquery how to offset scroll position

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the following code that scrolls to a certain element:

```
$('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#maincontent").offset().top
     }, 400);
```

However, I have a fixed navbar at the top and so would like to be able to offset this. How can I offset it by a number of pixels?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297688/jquery-offset-values-changes-by-scrolling-the-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#maincontent").offset().top - 100 // Means Less header height
},400);
```

Comment: Less header height from offset value , It will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#maincontent").scrollTop(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#maincontent").offset().top` just returns an integer, you only need to add or subtract to it to change the offset

```
$("#maincontent").offset().top - 100
```