# Offset <a> href = id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on `<a class="Navigation" id="WorldHeader" href="#WorldTitle">Go to World</a>`, my window put directly the div with the id directly on top. Is there a way to offset the window position when I click on the tag? My header is hiding the content, but I want to keep it.

Comment: There is an answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481571/jquery-how-to-offset-scroll-position

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Assuming based on the JQuery tag that, and using the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481571/jquery-how-to-offset-scroll-position) of [@WebMarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10621594/webmarie), the following solution must help you:

```js
$('#WorldHeader').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default <a> action.

  let myOffset = 50; // Pixels.
  let newScrollPosition = $("#WorldTitle").offset().top - myOffset;

  $('html, body').scrollTop(newScrollPosition); // Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar.
});
```

With animation:

```js
$('#WorldHeader').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let myOffset = 50; // Pixels.
  let animationDuration = 1000; // Miliseconds.
  let newScrollPosition = $("#WorldTitle").offset().top - myOffset;

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: newScrollPosition // Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar.
  }, animationDuration);
});
```

---

### Example of use

```js
$('#WorldHeader').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let myOffset = 50; // Pixels.
  let animationDuration = 1000; // Miliseconds.
  let newScrollPosition = $("#WorldTitle").offset().top - myOffset;

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: newScrollPosition // Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar.
  }, animationDuration);
});
```

```css
#WorldTitle {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="Navigation" id="WorldHeader" href="#WorldTitle">Go to World</a>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div id="WorldTitle"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```