# How prevent scroll to top after scroll to element

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

maybe it's newbie question but I'm really confused. I have code which supposed to navigate me on page. I have got "abc" navigation section, when I'm clicking on any letter, page scrolling to letter's section. When I'm clicking on another letter, page scrolling to top. Why it happening?

```
$('#abc li').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $("#"+$(this).text());
if(target.offset()){
    var offs = target.offset().top;
    console.log(target, offs);
    if ($(this).hasClass('pressed')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');
        $('#needToScroll').animate({scrollTop: offs - 115}, 400);
    }
    $(this).addClass('pressed');
}
else{
    console.log('undef sel');
} });
```

I've got fiddle of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SX5U4/30/). Pls someone explain me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use HTML anchors for scrolling to specific places in the list?

Comment: @Raibaz I tried, same effect. I think there is no trouble in markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offset()` returns a relative offset. You'll need to factor in the amount you've already scrolled. See here: [jquery offset values changes by scrolling the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297688/jquery-offset-values-changes-by-scrolling-the-page)