# Why does offset() depend on scroling

Tags: jquery, offset

According to [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp):

> The offset() method set or returns the offset coordinates for the
>   selected elements, relative to the document.

So `offset()` shouldn't depend on the position in the scrolling.

However, in my code:
my html is of the form:

```
...
<div class="paragraph"><div class="image"><img src="Pictures/2018-06-17_12-04-32.png">this is a picture</div> : text</div>
<div class="paragraph"><div class="image"><img src="Pictures/2018-05-16_16-03-00.png">this is another picture</div> : other text</div>
...
```

and the script is:

```
$("div.image").mouseover(function(){
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    console.log('pos_top :', pos.top);
```

Each time I'm scrolling, hovering over the picture displays a different number for `pos.top`. How is it possible?

Comment: Use `.position()` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery offset values changes by scrolling the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297688/jquery-offset-values-changes-by-scrolling-the-page)